# My application crashes after black screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a simple projet of an app on android studio using Win10

For now i'm just having two basic activity's Login and Main,
My project is synced,building and running successfully but at the moment when it opens on my android phone for a simulation it crashes instantly after a black screen remaining for mostly 2s

My app is connected to a firebase and i juste changer the wallpapper of the login screen but nothing more

That's my build.gradle :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.grantthornton"
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Thanks !

Comment: Add the crash logs

Comment: There's no logs it crashes when i open the app on my phone instantly without leaving any message
My build and running logs don't show any issues